# How to remove unnecessary all type of file in android studio on single click

Tags: android, android-studio

I need remove any type of unnecessary file in android studio that time I have follow bellow 2 step.

1. *Select file -> right click -> find usages*
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

It's long process to remove multipal file so any one suggest me best way to remove unnecessary all file in android studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> Android Studio -> Menu -> Refactor-> Remove Unused Resources

[image]

> OR

Use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and in the pop-up `EditText`, write `"Unused resources"` and

Like this

[image]

than Press <kbd>Enter key</kbd>

than  click on **`Remove All Unused Resources`** button

[image]